# Place max_execution_time in plugin

Tags: plugins, php

I have a client who has a php script execution timeout problem on a locally installed wordpress. I dont have an access to machine to do the test, so here is my question.

There is a custom plugin on that site that has all the php custom code in it. Can I just place:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

on top of plugin file and be sure it will work for entire front and back end?

Comment: In theory that should work (providing PHP is not in [safe mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590644/247223)). Having said that, the _real_ solution would be to find out _why_ the script is timing out (only the most intensive tasks should need that much time, and even then you would be better off looking at batching).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic The reason for timing out is this: admin uploads pdf to a post and then it is converted with ImageMagik and Ghostscript to a bunch of png files. When pdf file is big, it takes a while to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, but this will be applied to all the requests to the site which might actually bring it down if you have some infinite loop somewhere. A better way to do it is to find an action that is being used specifically in the upload process and call it only for that action.